# Is it possible to launch Unity3d Android app with enabled VR in non-VR mode?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

We developing an app for Oculus Quest with multiplayer and it's working fine. Now we've come to the moment where we need to have a non-VR spectator app that is built from exact same project, but allows to control only the flying camera to observe the scene with other users.

There is no problem with build for PC - just adding 'None' in VR devices list after 'Oculus' allow the app to switch to desktop mode (or skip VR device from code if it is presented), but if we want to build spectator app for Android with similar way, there is only the black screen from very start (even no Unity splash, but sounds tells us that app is working).

Disabling XR in Player Settings allow us to build for Android with required functionality, but then every single timewe should build twice - VR and non-VR apk. However, as we're using automated build server, that pipeline becomes a nightmare because first you're making VR build, then commiting changed settings, building again for non-VR, then changing settings back and commiting once more. That hell tooks an hour if not more and fills the repo's changelog with trash. Of course we could build locally, but it completely blocks the machine for next 30-40 minutes per build, so it is unacceptable.

Any ideas would be appreciated, my friends!